# Counter in Python for Rising Edges

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Dear Stackoverflow Community!

I am currently on my first Project working with a Raspberry Pi. The task is to implement a TY-010 Photo Interruptor Sensor. What I want to do is following:
I want to count the interruptions in a given time (i.e 2 seconds). So something like that(not C, in Python):
d count how many Interruptions there are.

```
int i = 0
while(time != 3){
if(outputFunction == True)
i += 1;
}
```

You can find the whole Code beneath:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO_PIN = 24
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

print "Sensor-Test [Press STRG+C, to exit the Test]"

def outputFunction(null):
        print("Signal detected")

GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=ausgabeFunktion, bouncetime=100) 

try:
        while True:
                time.sleep(1)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I am thankful for any help or advise !

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong defined ouputFunction, if you want a function without arguments just leave it empty, like this:

```
def outputFunction(): 
       print("Signal detected")
```

You can add a statement to verify if have passed x seconds, if you do time.sleep() you are stopping your code and if you press the button it won't work, so do it this way:

```
try:
    t_to_wait = 2 #Set to 2 secs
    t1 = time.time() #Get the start time
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(GPIO_PIN) == 1:
            outputFunction()
        if t1-time.time() > t_to_wait:
            break #Exit the loop if have passed t_to_wait seconds
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I also would recommend you to [read some examples](https://makezine.com/projects/tutorial-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins-and-python/) because it seems that you don't know python very well and the use of the GPIO module

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !! Yes you are right, it's my first day of python :) Meanwhile what do you think of my solution? :
'GPIO_PIN = 24
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
timeout = time.time()+10
    if GPIO.wait_for_edge(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.RISING):
    while True:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.FALLING)
    i +=1
    if i == 9 and time.time() < timeout:
    print(i)
    break'

Comment: I can't see the syntax very well and idk why you use the "i" for but actually you are right is better to check if the time elapsed is greater than the time we want instead of checking if it equally because the for loop could take more time than a second